# How to calculate the product of the values ​of two JTextFields next to each other and place them in the adjacent JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

I made a program where when the user selects something from the `JComboBox` a value will be placed in the `JTextFields` along with `TOTAL` and the user will input any number in the `POINTS` field and the product of the values ​​in the `EARNING` field next to each of the `TOTAL` & `POINTS` fields will show.
But here only the product of the `last two adjacent fields` is shown in each of the `EARNING` fields.

```
I want: 
200 * 1 = 200
100 * 2 = 200
200 * 4 = 800
100 * 6 = 600
```

But it always shows `600` the last product of two fields in each `EARNING` fields.

Here a Screenshot is attached for better understanding.

[image]

My Code for counting multiplication is given below:

```
private void calcCredit() {
    try {
        double summation = 1;
        int i = 0;
        for (JTextField textField : arr) {
            for(JTextField fields : arr1.subList(i, arr1.size())) {
                summation = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(fields.getText());
            }
            i++;
        }
        for(JTextField f : arr2) {
            f.setText(String.valueOf(summation));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Here all the `JTextFields` under `TOTAL` are added in an `ArrayList` named `arr`, all the `JTextFields` under `POINTS` are added in an `ArrayList` named `arr1` and the rest fields are added in `ArrayList` named `arr2`

Comment: BTW `arr`, `arr1` and `arr2` are kind of not very *expressive* - so you needed to explain their content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your code has the variable `i` and you increment `i` in the outer loop.  I think you were thinking of using `i` as index to the arrays.  And this would be the right direction.

The solution is to use i to refer to the row of the three fields.  For example, `arr[i], arr1[i], arr2[i]` would refers to all the three fields on row `i`. You need to compute the earning for each row and update the earning field for that row.

```
private void calcCredit() {
   for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
      double total   = Double.parseDouble(arr[i].getText());
      double points  = Double.parseDouble(arr1[i].getText());
      double earning = total * points;
      arr2[i].setText("" + earning);
   }
}
```

Comment: I use `ArrayList` that's why your solution doesn't work :( Sorry. Because it says `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<JTextField>`

Comment: Why not translate the code to using ArrayList?  The solution is the same.

Comment: `private void calcCredit() {
     for(int i = 0; i<arr.size() && i<arr1.size(); i++){
        double total   = Double.parseDouble(arr.get(i).getText());
        double points  = Double.parseDouble(arr1.get(i).getText());
        double earning = total * points;
        arr2.get(i).setText("" + earning);
     }
  }`

Ok i changed as you say and now its work! Thanks man for help :)

Comment: What to do in this case if I want to set the value of the adjacent field to 0 if any one of the two adjacent fields is empty?

Comment: You can use if-else.  For example, ``` if (arr[i].trim().equals("")) total = 0 else total = Double.parseDouble(arr[i].getText());```

Comment: BTW `"" + earning` is a bit *strange*, `String.vaueOf()` or `Double.toString()` would be a more direct way to do conversion to string

Comment: @user16320675 yes yes I did that.

Comment: @user16320675 I simply use implicit conversion and it's shorter and less typing.  We do it all the time such as ```System.out.println("There are " + count + " cats.")```.  But yes, ```String.valueOf``` and ```Double.toString``` would made the code better documented.

Comment: 1) "shorter and less typing", but not exactly reflecting what it is intended to do (convert Integer to String) - "*did the developer forgot to put a white space in there*?"; 2) "shorter", but not necessarily the compiled code; 3) there is a difference between what is in answer and what you commented now! Code in answer is concatenating with an empty String - intention is to convert; in the comment the main goal is to do concatenation (with non-empty strings) || I just don't like it, sorry :-|